# SQL query to get duplicate common values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
Table1   |  Table2
S1       |  S3
S2       |  S3   
S3       |  S9        
S4       |  S2
         |  S5
```

I have these two tables with one column. I want to get their intersection with duplicate values. i.e I want intersection result to be `(S2,S3,S3)`.

How can I get this result using SQL oracle query?
I am fairly new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select table2.column2
from table2
join table1 on table2.column2 = table1.column1
order by table2.column2
```

or alternatively, probably easier to understand, but less performant (is that a real word?):

```
select table2.column2
from table2
where column2 in (select column1 from table1)
order by table2.column2
```

These two queries aren't *quite* the same:

- The first will return each row table2 multiple times if table1 has the same value multiple times
- The second will return each row in table2 at most once, even if table1 lists them multiple times

The one to use depends on which is more suitable to you (ie what "duplicate values" means exactly)

Comment: I would like to point out, these two queries could produce different results depending on your actual data.  I suspect the first query will produce your desired results (assuming I'm understanding correctly), where the 2nd might produce the desired results.

Comment: @sgeddes Good point - they aren't quite the same - I've documented the difference in the answer. It's hard to know what is wanted and what "duplicates" *actually* means given the scant info in the question. It depends if the first table has only unique values (my money is on the second query)

Comment: I tried with the second query(easier to understand as you said) and it works for me. Thanks !

Comment: +1 for adding the explanations.  Difficult to infer, but looks like OP got what was needed.